# See function stop from locating defined class in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to define a class inside a function (for testing purpose) and put a value into
a function variable:

```
def foo():
    myvar = None
    class myclass:
        def run(self):
            myvar = 5

    mm = myclass()
    mm.run()
    print(myvar)
```

The above prints `None`

Is there any way other than `global` to make the `myvar` variable accessible from the class? The correct answer would print `5`

Comment: Nope, and that's isn't a good practive to do so. Don't try tricky manipulation

Comment: Add ```nonlocal myvar``` inside ```def run``` before assignment.

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this? This defeats the *entire purpose of a class*, which is to encapsulate state. As stated above though, you can use `nonlocal myvar`, which makes it assign to the closest enclosing scope, in this case, the local scope of the function. More reasonably, you should just have your `run` function return the value of `myvar`, and then simply capture the resulting value in the caller

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is not a helpful answer. Please answer the question first and then provide your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to assign a value to a variable outside the current scope without `global`. If you need to persist the value within the class you can define class variables instead. Example:

```
def foo():
    class Class:
        var_to_change = None
        def run (self):
            self.var_to_change = 5
    print (Class.var_to_change)
    instance = Class()
    instance.run()
    print (Class.var_to_change)
```

I haven't tested the above code but it should work in theory.

Comment: this will *also* print `None`. Also, in this case, it *is* possible with `nonlocal`.

Comment: I had no idea there was something like `nonlocal`. Wow!